# MS Access HOMEPATH saved exports

Tags: ms-access, export

I'm currently using Microsoft access 2007 and I have created several saved exports, on the program, i then set them up to buttons for use. this database has to be used on several different computers, and since my username won't suffice on the other machines as part of the directory that will hold the exports, I have been trying to use the %homepath% variable in windows, to replace the path in the Managed Data Tasks window but with no luck, has any one ran into this problem, or have another way to handle this, the files HAVE to be exported to the my documents folder on any windows system beyone xp

Comment: How exactly are you exporting the data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you export them to a shared drive?

Comment: unfortunately no, it's a distributed piece of software, so it's going on several different machines, outputting their own versions of the data.

Comment: another cheap solution is to use a hard-coded path from c:\, or, if you can reference the directory with the .mdb, export there

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following code into a standard code module.  Call as follows:

```
Debug.Print SpecFolder(CSIDL_PERSONAL)
```

---

```
'----- Special Folder declarations -------------------------------------------'
'"Identify the Location of Special Folders with API Calls" article in MSDN    '
'See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140088(office.10).aspx for more info'
''
'Declaration section for APIs needed to get the path to My Documents:'
Private Declare Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation _
                          Lib "Shell32" _
                              (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, ppidl As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList _
                          Lib "Shell32" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" _
                              (ByVal Pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long

Private Declare Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "ole32" (ByVal pvoid As Long)

Private Const MAX_PATH = 260
Private Const NOERROR = 0

Public Enum CSIDL
    CSIDL_PERSONAL = &H5             'Current user My Documents'
    CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = &H10    'Current user Desktop'
    CSIDL_MYPICTURES = 39            'Current user My Pictures'
End Enum
'================================================================='

Function SpecFolder(ByVal Folder As CSIDL) As String
Dim PidlFound As Long, FolderFound As Long
Dim Pidl As Long, strPath As String

    'Create buffer to hold path'
    strPath = Space(MAX_PATH)
    'Find Pointer to item ID List (PIDL)'
    PidlFound = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, Folder, Pidl)
    If PidlFound = NOERROR Then
        'Look up path to special folder using the PIDL we found above'
        FolderFound = SHGetPathFromIDList(Pidl, strPath)
        If FolderFound Then
            'Return only the portion of the string buffer we want'
            '  (everything up to the null terminating character)'
            SpecFolder = Left$(strPath, _
                               InStr(1, strPath, vbNullChar) - 1)
        End If
    End If
    'When an API function creates a PIDL, memory is automatically allocated to storing it'
    '   CoTaskMemFree frees that allocated memory'
    CoTaskMemFree Pidl
End Function
```

Comment: Wow your code is really nice, but i don't believe it will help me in this situation, i am trying to print from a saved export, in the managed data tasks, box, i am using a bit of code here

Function Complete_Email_List_Macro()
On Error GoTo Complete_Email_List_Macro_Err

    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-CompleteEmailList"
    
Complete_Email_List_Macro_Exit:
    Exit Function

Complete_Email_List_Macro_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Complete_Email_List_Macro_Exit

End Function

my problem is the directory that the saved export is saving to, as it's not global enough for all machines

Comment: I see.  One option might be to refactor your code to use one of the `DoCmd.Transfer` methods (eg, TransferText, TransferDatabase, etc.).  That will give you programmatic control over the export destination.